# Submitting multiple values for the same key in a POST request in Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How would I submit a POST request in Ruby's Mechanize gem, with multiple values for the same key?

E.g. I want `foo=1` and `foo=2` to be sent. I tried

```
parameter = {'foo' => ['1', '2']}
Mechanize.new.post('http://somewebsite.com', parameters)
```

But using [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/), I only get '12' for 'foo', instead of '1' for one value of 'foo' and '2' for another value of 'foo'.

Also: the reason I'm doing this is because I want to select multiple values in a multiple select list, but calling `select_all` on the select list and submitting the form doesn't seem to work, so I'm trying to manually submit the POST data instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options:

1. Make the second foo a symbol:

   parameters = {'foo' => '1', :foo => '2'}
2. Construct the post body yourself:

   parameters = 'foo=1&foo=2'

Comment: Amazing. Seems like RequestBin still stupidly thinks that there is one value of one parameter (not concatenated this time though), but the actual webpage works as intended now. Thanks!